# Brute force 4-digit combinations

Tags: autoit, brute-force, cracking

I want to brute force 4-digit combinations (<kbd>0</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd>) by simulating number-pad key-presses. How to do this using AutoIt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this and add [`ControlSend()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) or [`Send()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) or [`ControlSetText()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSetText.htm) (or something else) to put `$i` into your input field and that's it.

```
; 0000 - 9999

Global $start = 0
Global $end = 9999

For $i = $start To $end
    ConsoleWrite(StringFormat('%04i', $i) & @CRLF)
Next
```